# Listview Details view not displaying anything

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, detailsview

I'm trying to use a details view mode of a ListView in winforms, but none of the items are displaying. The listview itself is growing as items are added, but nothing is being displayed.

It is displaying the items in list mode, but just not in Details mode.

I have used the following code, any ideas?

```
forms_listView.Columns.Add("URL");
forms_listView.Columns.Add("Position");
```

and

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Tag = form;
lvi.Text = form.URL;
lvi.Name = "URL";
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvi, "Position");
subItem.Name = "Position";
subItem.Text = ""+form.Position;
lvi.SubItems.Add(subItem);
forms_listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Comment: Your problem is not in that bit of code.

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks. Due to your comment, I looked around elsewhere and found it :) Never realized that clear removes columns as well

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found my problem. I was calling the `listview.Clear()` method which in the documentation says that it removes all items and all columns, which was causing no items to be displayed.

Comment: lol I've been trying to debug the same problem for past 20 mins! thanks :)  need to call listview.Items.Clear()

Comment: Answer was useful to C++ too, as I needed to call `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle` and `ListView_InsertColumn` first (the other views looked fine).

Comment: It's always the dumbest little thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

```
forms_listView.Columns.Add("First Column Title"); 
... 
forms_listView.Columns.Add("Last Column Title");
```